# Blogger - Sidebar moved to the bottom but only on the homepage

Tags: themes, blogger, sidebar

I've got a little problem with my blog http://www.cinscreations.com

So I'm not really experienced with code and I tried to search for an answer here but can't find it and on the blogger forum I got redirected to this website or the theme developer, which I contacted but haven't heard back yet.

I don't think I changed anything but somehow two days ago my sidebar on my blog moved to the bottom, I don't know if it's aligned wrong or maybe something else is the problem but somehow this only happens on the homepage. I've checked all posts and the sidebar is exactly where it should be, it's also on the right on my pages.
So I'm thinking that the slider is the problem but it always worked fine and I'm sure I didn't change anything with the slider.

So please if somebody can help me... and please let me know if I need to insert any code...as I said I'm not that experienced with HTML or CSS.

Comment: it would be impossible/extremely hard for someone to help you without the code.

Comment: There might be some setting in blog which might fix it. Since it is a template it should work fine, all page.

Comment: @sid8491 what part of the code should I insert and how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to fix this yet? Seems to be working fine for me. Normally this is an issue with CSS.